# Migrate php code to js using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code in php and I can not migrate to JS it to any help?

```
foreach ($rubros as $key) {    
   $rubro[$key->area][$key->rubro]=array();    
   $rubro[$key->area][$key->rubro][0]=0;    
   $rubrocant[$key->area][$key->rubro]=array();    
   array_push($rubrocant[$key->area][$key->rubro], $key->cant);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(rubros, function(value, key) {
    rubro[value.area][value.rubro] = [];
    rubro[value.area][value.rubro][0] = 0;
    ....
});
```

Comment: I throw away an error!, Because when placing the second index does not exist then ... you can not place the empty array ... angular.min.js:124 TypeError: Cannot set property 'Condiciones de seguridad' of undefined

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to reduce the impression that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to explain... He's asking how to do a foreach loop in angular. I was just trying to show him the syntax.

Comment: Gonzalo - Of course that's going to be the case. If the second index is undefined it's going to fail. What do you WANT your program to do if the index is undefined? Set it to 0? I don't know... The PHP code is going to fail too is the second index is undefined. So you need to check for undefined values and do... whatever you need to do.